# R bootnet case-dropping bootstrap stops running with no specific error message

Tags: r, crash

I'm running a network analysis in R using qgraph and bootnet. When running the case-dropping bootstrap to estimate correlation-stability coefficients of centrality indices, the algorithm simply "gets stuck" with no specific error message.

I know there are issues with my data (e.g., the sample is quite small, N = 112, a subset of variables are highly correlated with each other, while a few others share little to no correlation with the rest). However, it's never happened to me that the analysis would simply stop mid-way and I'm trying to figure out what exactly is causing this.

This is the current code:

```
netdt23 <- select(dati,
                 ToM,
                 "MT" = Mentalization,
                 "PpR" = Popular_Response,
                 "CM" = Complete_Meaning,
                 "PE" = Problem_Elaboration,
                 "PS" = Problem_Solving,
                 "NE" = Negative_Emotions
                 )

npn23 <- huge.npn(netdt23)

net23 <- estimateNetwork(
  npn23,
  default = "EBICglasso",
  corMethod = "cor_auto",
  lambda.min.ratio = 1e-15,
  threshold = TRUE
)

btfun <- function(x){
  nt <- estimateNetwork(x,
                  default = "EBICglasso",
                  corMethod = "cor_auto",
                  lambda.min.ratio = 1e-15,
                  threshold = TRUE
                  )
  return(nt$graph)
}

btntCen23 <- bootnet(
  npn23, fun = btfun, type = "case",
  statistics = c("edge", "strength", "betweenness"), #"closeness", 
  nBoots = 2000,
  caseMin = .05, caseMax = .95, caseN = 19)
```

While running, bootnet occasionally gives warnings and/or errors, but these are never the last output before crashing (meaning that, apparently, the analysis keeps running past these issues and stops later). Such as:

- Error in lav_samplestats_icov(COV = cov[[g]], ridge = ridge.eps, x.idx = x.idx[[g]], : lavaan ERROR: sample covariance matrix is not positive-definite
- An empty network was selected to be the best fitting network. Possibly set 'lambda.min.ratio' higher to search more sparse networks. You can also change the 'gamma' parameter to improve sensitivity (at the cost of specificity).

Any help would be greatly appreciated. If I left out necessary information, please let me know and I'll edit the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the result of `estimateNetwork` in `bootnet`:

```
netdt23 <- select(dati,
                 ToM,
                 "MT" = Mentalization,
                 "PpR" = Popular_Response,
                 "CM" = Complete_Meaning,
                 "PE" = Problem_Elaboration,
                 "PS" = Problem_Solving,
                 "NE" = Negative_Emotions
                 )

net23 <- estimateNetwork(
  npn23,
  default = "EBICglasso",
  corMethod = "cor_auto",
  lambda.min.ratio = 1e-15,
  threshold = TRUE
)

btntCen23 <- bootnet(net23, type = "case",
  statistics = c("edge", "strength", "betweenness"), 
  nBoots = 2000,
  caseMin = .05, caseMax = .95, caseN = 19)
```

As for what goes wrong here, that is hard to say without the data. But three things to note:

1. The `cor_auto` command doesn't work well especially with small sample sizes. I would use `corMethod = "spearman"` instead.
2. `lambda.min.ratio` shouldn't be set this small. Leave it to the default value.
3. By setting `caseMax = .95` you drop 95% of the cases in some samples, meaning that you will estimate networks based on 5 to 6 people, which is very small and will likely lead to errors.